# Ubuntu Keeps Screen Freezing

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, freeze

I have yet to install linux on my spare HDD because no matter what I do it will just freeze up. For example: trying to install linux it will freeze my screen and when i try ubuntu w/o installing it will freeze after a few seconds on the desktop. Not sure what's causing it becasue i've been able to use it on my laptop a day before.

PC:
mobo: msi gaming 970,
ram: 16gb,
cpu: amd fx 4300,
gpu: gtx 960 (nvidia, which i believe is my problem),
linux: ubuntu 16.04 lts

p.s. i was able to install ubuntu a few times on this exact pc before, but all of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: Prefer 16.10 (or at least 16.04.2) because the newer kernel can handle that broken IOMMU without additional Grub parameters. But the graphics card is indeed the main issue. In order to avoid freezing use `nomodeset` in the live session and eventually during the first boot before installing the recommended nvidia drivers.